# How do I get the connectionstring of a ServiceBusClient?

Tags: c#, azure, client, connection-string, azureservicebus

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
```

---

I currently have a `ServiceBusClient` where I pass the `connectionString` as a parameter to its constructor:

```
var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
```

Now imagine I have another class called `Handler` which expect a `ServiceBusClient` as a parameter to its constructor:

```
var handler = new Handler(client);
```

Now inside the constructor of `Handler`, is there any way where I can get the exact `connectionString` which `client` got as a parameter to its constructor?

```
public Handler(ServiceBusClient client)
{
    var connectionStringOfClient = ...?
}
```

Haven't found a simple property yet offering said `connectionString`, so I'm wondering if there is any other way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't. Only property that you can get out of the `ServiceBusClient` is [`FullyQualifiedNamespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.fullyqualifiednamespace?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusClient_FullyQualifiedNamespace).

The reason you can't get the connection string information from the client is because there are many ways by which you can create an instance of ServiceBusClient and using connection string is just one of them. For all the possible constructor overloads, please see [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet#constructors).